# Is it possible to set multiple decorators for a single node?

Tags: ractivejs

Something like

```
<button decorator='initbutton:p1, p2; tooltip:Text' />
```

I have found a decorator helper plugin for combining decorators:
http://martypdx.github.io/ractive-decorators-helpers/
Is it the best option right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ractive-multi-decorator`.

First install it:

```
npm install ractive-multi-decorator --save
```

Then add it to ractive:

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
    ...
    decorators: {
        multi: require('ractive-multi-decorator')
    },
    ...
});
```

Then use it:

```
<div 
    id="myelement"
    decorator="multi:{ 
        localdecorator: [ {{ dynamicArg1 }}, arg2, arg3 ], 
        globaldecorator: {{singleArg}}, 
        anotherdecorator: true 
    }"
></div>
```

Credits go to akhouzy and martypdx.

Comment: Thanks! 
Will try to use it first and then will change the accepted answer.

Comment: Also tested this https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/399#issuecomment-128687437 — works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Ractive doesn't natively support multiple decorators, at least not yet. The [decorator helper plugin](http://martypdx.github.io/ractive-decorators-helpers/) that you found is the best option right now.

Someone [opened an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/399) to request this feature if you want to chime in.